# Are there StringCollections in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, string

I was needing a StringCollection field in my database but I don't know if MySQL has anything of the sort, does it?

Answer (score 2):

String collections are usually implemented as a 1-to-many relation with a foreign key.  For example, to add a string collection for rows in Table1, you'd set up Table2 like:

```
Table1: id, name, ...
Table2: Table1Id foreign key references Table1(id), strValue, ...
```

Example values where `Table1` contains football teams, with a string collection of players:

```
Table1: 1, "Manchester United"
        2, "Liverpool"

Table2: 1, "Bobby Charlton"
        1, "Wayne Rooney" 
        2, "Steven Gerrard"
        2, "Michael Owen"
```

Answer (score 0):

There is the mysql [SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set.html) type.